# Observer pattern design and RXJS library

Tags: design-patterns, rxjs, observable, observer-pattern, rxjs-observables

I am a novice user in the library RXJS and trying to figure out how to use properly Observable and Subjects.
I am trying to draw parallels with pattern design Observer.
At some point, I have a question if the instance of the Observable from the library RXJS is a special case of Observer pattern design?

Answer (score 5):

An `Observable` is, *by definition*, an entity which emits data over time. This sounds a bit vague and, at the same time, very interesting.

In my opinion, all the RxJS' magic is achieved with **linked lists**.

Whenever you create an `Observable` using `new Observable(subscriber => {})`, you are defining the source, or the **HEAD** node of a linked list. Also, have you ever wondered why the parameter is called `subscriber` or `observer`? I'll try to share my view on that as well.

The **main linked list** is created with the help of [`Observable.pipe()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L439):

```js
pipe(...operations: OperatorFunction<any, any>[]): Observable<any> {
  return operations.length ? pipeFromArray(operations)(this) : this;
}

export function pipeFromArray<T, R>(fns: Array<UnaryFunction<T, R>>): UnaryFunction<T, R> {
  if (fns.length === 0) {
    return identity as UnaryFunction<any, any>;
  }

  if (fns.length === 1) {
    return fns[0];
  }

  return function piped(input: T): R {
    return fns.reduce((prev: any, fn: UnaryFunction<T, R>) => fn(prev), input as any);
  };
}
```

and [`Observable.lift()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L66):

```js
protected lift<R>(operator?: Operator<T, R>): Observable<R> {
  const observable = new Observable<R>();
  observable.source = this;
  observable.operator = operator;
  return observable;
}
```

As you know, in RxJS there are many operators. An `operator` is a function which returns **another function** whose argument is an `Observable`(of type `T`) and whose return value is also an `Observable`(of type `R`).

For example, [`map()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/map.ts#L45):

```js
export function map<T, R>(project: (value: T, index: number) => R, thisArg?: any): OperatorFunction<T, R> {
  return function mapOperation(source: Observable<T>): Observable<R> {
    if (typeof project !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('argument is not a function. Are you looking for `mapTo()`?');
    }
    return lift(source, new MapOperator(project, thisArg));
  };
}
```

So, when you have

```js
const src$ = new Observable(s => /* ... */)
  .pipe(
    map(/* ... */)
  )
```

a few things will happen:

- first, it will create the `Observable` instance; the provided callback(in this case `s => ...`) will be stored in the [`_subscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L34-L38) property
- `pipe()` is invoked; it will return `fns[0]`, in this case the `mapOperation` function
- `mapOperation` will be invoked with the `Observable` instance as its argument(from `pipeFromArray(operations)(this)`); when invoked, it will call `source.lift(new MapOperator(project, thisArg));`; `Observable.lift()` is what adds nodes to this linked list; as you can see, a node(apart from `HEAD`) holds the `source` and the `operator` which represents it

When you subscribe to `src$`, based on this list, another one will be created. In this one, each node will be a `Subscriber`. The creation of this list is based on the fact that each `operator` [must have a `call` method](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/c570750b7856e31eeae6122437cc44863d6d07be/api_guard/dist/types/index.d.ts#L444)

```js
export interface Operator<T, R> {
  call(subscriber: Subscriber<R>, source: any): TeardownLogic;
}
```

[`MapOperator` is no exception](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/map.ts#L58):

```js
export class MapOperator<T, R> implements Operator<T, R> {
  constructor(private project: (value: T, index: number) => R, private thisArg: any) {
  }

  call(subscriber: Subscriber<R>, source: any): any {
    return source.subscribe(new MapSubscriber(subscriber, this.project, this.thisArg));
  }
}
```

the relations between the `Subscriber` nodes are established in `Observable.subscribe()`

In this case, the `s` parameter from `new Observable(s => ...)`(the above example) will be the `MapSubscriber`.

It may seem that I deviated from the question, but with the above explanations I wanted to demonstrate that there is not much of the `Observer` pattern here.

This pattern can be achieved with a `Subject`, which [extends `Observable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L16):

```js
export class Subject<T> extends Observable<T> implements SubscriptionLike { }
```

and this means that you can use `Subject.pipe(...)` and `Subject.subscribe(subscriber)`. What `Subject` does in order to achieve this pattern is to have a *custom* [`_subscribe`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L108) method:

```js
_subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<T>): Subscription {
  if (this.closed) {
    throw new ObjectUnsubscribedError();
  } else if (this.hasError) {
    subscriber.error(this.thrownError);
    return Subscription.EMPTY;
  } else if (this.isStopped) {
    subscriber.complete();
    return Subscription.EMPTY;
  } else {
    
    // !!!
    this.observers.push(subscriber);
    return new SubjectSubscription(this, subscriber);
  }
}
```

as you can see, the `Subject` class keeps track of its observers(subscribers), so that when it emits a value, with [`Subject.next()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L48), all its observers will receive it:

```js
next(value: T) {
  if (this.closed) {
    throw new ObjectUnsubscribedError();
  }
  if (!this.isStopped) {
    const { observers } = this;
    const len = observers.length;
    const copy = observers.slice();
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      copy[i].next(value!);
    }
  }
  }
```

As a side node, a `Subject` can act as a `Subscriber` as well, so you don't have to manually call `Subject.{next, error, complete}()` all the time. You can achieve that with something like this

```js
src$.pipe(subjectInstance);
```